# Como criar um arquivo txt?

Tags: android

No Java eu uso o `PrintWriter` e funciona perfeitamente, mas no Android estou apanhando muito, não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa? É uma coisa simples, mas estou travado. Eu precisava criar um `.txt` simples com uma *string*. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: ...em um diretório que você possa visitar depois com um gerenciador de arquivos para poder ver o arquivo, correto?

Comment: sim, apenas criar um txt na área de trabalho ou nos meus documentos por exemplo.

Answer (score 9):

Primeiro você deve inserir no AndroidManifest.xml a permissão para gravar no sdcard, antes da tag application :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Depois de criar os atributos, você vai criar o diretório:

```
private File diretorio;
private String nomeDiretorio;
private String diretorioApp;
```

Após isso, você deve definir o diretório:

```
diretorioApp = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            + "/"+nomeDiretorio+"/";

diretorio = new File(diretorioApp);
diretorio.mkdirs();
```

Depois de você criar o diretório onde o arquivo vai ser salvo, pode criar o arquivo txt:

```
//Quando o File() tem um parâmetro ele cria um diretório.
//Quando tem dois ele cria um arquivo no diretório onde é informado.
File fileExt = new File(diretorioApp, nomeArquivo);

//Cria o arquivo
fileExt.getParentFile().mkdirs();

//Abre o arquivo
FileOutputStream fosExt = null;
fosExt = new FileOutputStream(fileExt);

//Escreve no arquivo
fosExt.write(etTexto.getText().toString().getBytes());

//Obrigatoriamente você precisa fechar
fosExt.close();
```

Qualquer dúvida, da um toque ;D