# Como criar um arquivo de texto no Android?

Tags: java, android

Já procurei por vários exemplos e scripts na internet e até mesmo aqui no stackoverflow porém ainda não consegui criar um arquivo de texto no android,
o ultimo código que eu tentei utilizar sem êxito foi esse:

[Como criar um arquivo txt?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82498/como-criar-um-arquivo-txt-no-android)

Simplesmente compilava e tal, porém não gerava o arquivo, o meu Manifest já está com as permissões necessárias.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa conferir a permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo que salva arquivo de texto no device.

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basta você chamá-lo, dessa forma:

```
generateNoteOnSD(this, "nome_do_arquivo", "texto_do_arquivo");
```

Comment: Oque eu preciso mudar nesse código pra salvar na memória interna do celular? o meu celular não possui cartão SD.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html Esse link pode te ajudar, explica sobre armazenamento interno e externo.