# Arquivo TXT no android

Tags: android, delphi, arquivo, firemonkey

Como faço para gravar um arquivo TXT no android usando o delphi 10 Seatle?
já tentei dessa forma e só da erro;

```
  try
    file1 := TIniFile.Create(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDownloadsPath+PathDelim+'postogestorcoletor.ini');
    file1.WriteString('postogestorcoletor','testeteste', 'asasasasasas');
    file1.Free;
  finally
    ShowMessage('Erro ao criar arquivo');
  end;
```

Comment: Faça a operação sem o Try (tratamento de erro) para sabermos qual a exceção está ocorrendo. A propósito, em qual linha está ocorrendo o erro?

Comment: Pesquisando no próprio SOpt, encontrei a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82504/49822

Comment: Tirei o bloco try e não mostra erro, simplesmente não cria o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei o motivo de você criar o arquivo no Android, normalmente crio o arquivo em pasta .ini e quando faço o `Deploy` mando o arquivo junto.

Espero ter ajudado.

```
uses
   System.IOUtils   

{$IF DEFINED (ANDROID)}
file1 := TIniFile.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'postogestorcoletor.ini');
try
  file1.WriteString('postogestorcoletor','testeteste', 'asasasasasas');
finally
  FreeAndNil(file1);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Até cria o arquivo, porém cria na pasta android/
data/com.embarcadero.Scanner. O ideal seria na raiz.

Comment: @AlexandreVieira tente mudar para TPath.GetDownloadsPath

Comment: Já fiz isso, mas agora já mudei a forma de persistência para banco de dados SQLite, ta dando uns erros, dependendo abro mais uma pergunta hehehe