# Mantendo dados na aplicação depois de atualizar na play store

Tags: react-native, expo

Saudações colegas, preciso de uma ajuda com um pequeno problema que estou tendo com um app desenvolvido com o expo

Quando atualizamos a versão do nosso app na loja mudamos a arquitetura do projeto e passamos a utilizar o expo, porém os usuários estão sendo deslogados pois os dados de login não estão sendo mantidos, alguem poderia me indicar um caminho para resolver a situação?

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Não ficou claro pra mim se a perda da "sessão" acontece na migração apenas ou é um problema da arquitetura nova. Então: o usuário precisa relogar quantas vezes após atualizar o app?

Comment: a perda de sessão acontece na migração, pois não tenho acesso ao token do usuário pra autenticar ele após ele atualizar o app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a nova versão não possui um mecanismo para recuperar o token da versão antiga (como armazená-lo na memória interna para ler posteriormente) e você disponibilizou a atualização para a totalidade dos usuários, acredito que não será mais possível resolver de maneira eficiente. Se o novo lançamento está em estágio beta e/ou você tem como submeter uma nova atualização com a versão antiga, sugiro criptografar os dados da sessão na versão antiga, persisti-los no armazenamento interno e lê-los na versão nova.

### ATUALIZAÇÃO

Um passo a passo, resumido:

1. Armazene o token existente no app que será descontinuado: pode ser em txt, como explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82504/7499);
2. Leia o token no app novo: explicado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51074967/3237900). Se estiver usando Expo, precisará [deste método aqui](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options).

Isto deve ser suficiente para a primeira execução do app após a atualização. Agora você deve persistir o token "no domínio" do app novo (da mesma forma que faria se não houvesse app antigo). Minha sugestão é usar a biblioteca [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Comment: Ainda está em beta interno para os testes, desculpe a ignorancia mas como eu posso persistir esses dados no armazenamento interno? Eu tentei com o persistor do redux porém não manteve os dados

Comment: Resposta atualizada.